# How to update version in Azure DevOps for a .Net Standard Library

Tags: azure-devops

I have a .Net Standard library in GitHub and am trying to create a build and release pipeline.  This works fine, but I'm struggling to work out how to update the version in the build.  There's a few MarketPlace plug-ins available, but they all seem to be geared towards .Net Framework applications.  Is there a way that's build in the DevOps that allows this - it seems a standard piece of functionality?

Answer (score 3):

As Remco said above use "dotnet build /p:version={yourVersionNumber} ..." this will tag your build with the given version number so you can see it in the dll file version property.

Followed by "dotnet publish --no-build ..." so it will publish your dlls without rebuilding and default version to "1.0.0.0". Your published content will retain the version number you specified in the dotnet build.

Both steps above can be done using PowerShell.

Hope it helps.

Links to dotnet build and publish:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build?tabs=netcore2x
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore21

Comment: thank you, you put me in the right direction for fixing this, I had to set no build on my test, pack and publish tasks in azure!

Answer (score 1):

This is of course dependent on how you are performing your build you could do the following:

Using the .net core task/dotnet build (this also works for standard libs) you can add the version as an argument:
[image]
In this example i use the build-number but that could be whatever you prefer.

Comment: When I try this, I get the error: error CS7034: The specified version string does not conform to the required format - major[.minor[.build[.revision]]]

Comment: The Build.Buildnumber was only an example but if you want to use it, make sure that the Buildnumber generates a valid semver string.  you can configure it under the Options section in your build definition

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here didn't work for me because we're now forced to use YAML to configure everything, but I did cobble together an alternative solution in my pipeline definition:

```
variables:
  projectVersion: '0.0'
  buildNumber: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  versionNumber: '$(projectVersion).$(buildNumber)'

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $input_path = (Get-ChildItem -Path "YourDirectory\" -Include SampleLibrary.csproj -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
      $regex = '(?<=<Version>).*?(?=<\/Version>)'
      $version = Select-String -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
      Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=projectVersion]$version"
```

This will set the version number to a value like '1.1.8.547'. You can massage those pieces as you see fit, perhaps leaving it as a 3-part value with auto-incrementing build number, or you could omit the build number entirely and rely solely on the version number defined in the project itself.

The gist of the PowerShell script here is that it will first retrieve the .csproj file in the specified directory. Then it uses a regex match to pull the value out of the file and stores it in the $version variable. The last line is writing the value of $version to the projectVersion variable defined in the YAML, which you can then reference down the line.